# What will be the tension force in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Suppose I have a block of mass $2\, {\rm kg}$ sitting on my table. Then I connect a string to it and pull it vertically upwards. The resultant acceleration is vertically upwards: $2.2\, {\rm ms}^{-2}$. What will be the tension force in the string?

**My attempt:**

Now, there are two forces acting on the body, the force of gravity vertically downwards $(mg)$ and the force that I used to pull the block vertically upwards with $F_{up}$. Now, the tension force $T$

$$F_{up}-mg=T$$

I don't need to know the value of $F_{up}$ because I know the value of $T$ already. It is $2.2\, {\rm ms}^{-2}\times2\,{\rm kg}=4.4\,{\rm N}$.

**My book's attempt:**

According to my book,
$$T-mg=ma$$
$$T=mg+ma$$
$$T=m(g+a)$$
$$T=2(9.8+2.2)$$
$$T=24\,{\rm N}.$$
I don't understand what my book did. Is my way correct or is my book's way correct?

Comment: The book is correct:  best to do $F=ma$ from Newton's 2nd Law and fill in the forces on the left hand side to get the first line from your book.  If the upward acceleration were $0$, your way would give $T=0$, but there would be tension in the string because of the weight of the book

Comment: @JohnHunter Isn't tension force=net force? Could you please explain the book's thought process to me kind sir: I can't seem to understand it

Comment: when the book accelerates upwards there is a resultant force acting upwards from $F=ma = 2\times 2.2$, but the resultant force is $T-mg$ (from a free body diagram), then you get the book's first line.  All the best with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always draw a free body diagram.

Your $F_{up}$ is the tension in the string, and your $T$ is the net force $=Ma$ acting upward.  See the free body diagram below.

Hope this helps.

[image]